# Can I Install any other Linux os than Ubuntu on a BQ Aquaris M10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware-compatibility, tablet

A few months ago I bought a BQ Aquaris M10 FHD Ubuntu version, but since some time the support for the installed touch version of Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-15) was stopped and there is no newer version I could install. So is there any way I could install another linux os like arch? I have had just some experiences with Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, Zorin and some others, but I have no experience about whether an OS runs on a device or not, so I would appreciate any help!

there is also this link to the firmware files provided by bq: http://www.mibqyyo.com/de-download/categorias/tablets/serie-aquaris-m/aquaris-m10-fhd-ubuntu-edition/

ps: the device has a MediaTek Quad Core MT8163A cpu and a MediaTek Mali-T720 MP2 gpu

Answer (score 1):

Installing an OS in a ARM based device is not the same as installing it in a desktop/laptop PC. The latter is easier than ever, the former requires lots of expertise. Expertise that, according to your description of past Linux experiences, you don't have.

Ubuntu Touch is still being (unofficially) developed by the [UBports Community](https://ubports.com/). I suggest you use their [installer](https://ubports.com/ubuntu-touch/get-ut) to update your device.